# "as string" versus toString()

Tags: typescript

I am writing some unit tests using jasmine. If I use:

```
let arg0 : string = http.put.calls.argsFor(0) as string;
if(arg0.search(...
```

then I get the error `arg0.search` is not a function. Intellisense shows that arg0 is an array and not a string as expected. If I instead use:

```
let arg0 : string = http.put.calls.argsFor(0).toString();
if(arg0.search(...
```

it works. Intellisense shows that the argsFor function signature has any as the return type. When called it returns an array.

Why does the "as string" version not work and why am I not getting a compile error given arg0 in that case ends up holding an array instead of a string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`as string` is a TypeScript construct, as it is removed when compiled so javascript doesn't even know about it.

`toString()` is a JavaScript method that actually takes what is returned in the previous method and converts it to a string. This isn't removed at compile time.

Comment: So what you are saying is that when I'm specifying type information in Typescript, the transpiler can't always determine whether it is actually correct, in contrast to languages like C#; Java?

Comment: @pere57 typescript only exists at compile time. So - you cannot compare it with IL or JVM bytecodes, correct.

Comment: @zerkms I see. So in TypeScript "as" is just a type assertion to help the TypeScript compiler analyse the code; it doesn't actually change the variable to which it is applied . On the other hand,  the C# "as" is an operator and actually performs a type conversion at runtime.

Comment: @pere57 that is correct. That is also the same when casting like this `<string>myVar`.

Answer (score 7):

Completely different things.

## `as string`

This is a type assertion

- More https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion

## `toString()`

This is a function call

- More https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: The first link is broken

Comment: There's a small typo in the first link, it should point to: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion